# MKMapView Cannot Set Center By Location

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, mkannotation

I want to get current location and animate to this coordinate on MKMapView. I got current location but I didn't do animate to this location on MKMapView. How can I animate to current location with blue dot ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    locationManager.delegate=self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

    location = [locationManager location];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    coord.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
    coord.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
    lat = coord.latitude;
    longt = coord.longitude;

    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:coord animated:TRUE];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views

{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    id<MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate] ,250,250);
    [mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: you want to set mapview center by user's current location .M i right ?

Comment: yes, I want to set mapview center by user's current location

Answer (score 1):

```
self.mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollow
```

this will follow the users location with a blue dot, which seems to be what you want to implement

Comment: Nothing happened. Map can't zoom to current location.

Comment: are your location delegate methods being called? are you running on the device or simulator?

Comment: if you put a breakpoint in the didUpdateLocation method is it being hit?

Answer (score 0):

You have to register for KVO notifications of userLocation.location property of MKMapView.

To do this, put this code in viewDidLoad: of your ViewController or anywhere in the place where your map view is initialized.

```
[self.mapView.userLocation addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"location"  
           options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)   context:NULL];
```

Then implement this method to receive KVO notifications

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath  ofObject:(id)object  change:(NSDictionary *)change  context:(void *)context
 {  

    if ([self.mapView showsUserLocation])
    {  
        [self moveOrZoomOrAnythingElse];
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Map still can't move or zoom to user's location.